# Vincular Storyboard con ViewController / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

![estuve creando esta aplicacion, que pasa de una pantalla de inicio de sesion y pude vincular el storyboard con el viewController, pero al pasar a la segunda pantalla, no me permite vincular las vistas con el codigo][1]alguien podria ayudarme con este error?, no me permite vincular las vistas con el viewController, ni con la pantalla dividida ni desde codigo

```
    //
//  HomeViewController.swift
//  
//
//  Created by  on 13/10/22.
//

import UIKit

enum ProviderType: String{
    case basic
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var providerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var closeSessionButton: UIButton!
    
    private let email: String
    private let provider: ProviderType
    
    init(email: String, provider: ProviderType) {
        self.email = email
        self.provider = provider
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Inicio"
    }
    
    @IBAction func closeSessionButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

[1]

Comment: seria bueno que cambiaras la imagen a código, me refiero a la parte que  contiene el código

Comment: En `HomeViewController` no puedes agregar ningún elemento (botones, labels)? En el storyboard tienes agregado en el `View Controller` la clase `HomeViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Analiza que la segunda Storyboard tenga asignado el `ViewController` desde el cual la quieras manejar.
Crea el `VierwController` utilizando `Cocoa Touch Class` y te ahorras problemas.

[image]

Si ello no funciona, prueba lo siguiente:

1. Crea un nuevo Storyboard file;
2. Copia el `scene` que hiciste anteriormente y pegalo dentro;
3. Elimina el scence en blanco y asignale el `ViewController` correcto;
4. Por último elima el storyboard file anterior.